# can i use foundation 5 with bourbon Neat?

Tags: zurb-foundation, bourbon, neat

hey guys I am totally blown away by the power of clean semantic mark-up.My Question is that can i just use the UI components of fundation with Neat? has anyone tried it yet?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You absolutely could, though it would muddy your semantic mark-up and bloat your app some. Not sure if you're using Rails, but: [How can I use two css frameworks in one rails app? (Using foundation and bourbon neat on same app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620216/how-can-i-use-two-css-frameworks-in-one-rails-app-using-foundation-and-bourbon)

Have you taken a look at [refills](http://refills.bourbon.io/)? It provides you with a lot of pre-packaged UI components built on top of the bourbon/neat/bitters stack that you can easily tinker with to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. if you think the question is good you can upvote it.